# What Is Meant By Database/Web is Details

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I am reading this [article](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) by ["Uncle" Bob Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin). He mentions under the heading **Frameworks and Drivers.**

> The Web is a detail. The database is a detail.

I am not able to understand what he means by "detail". Please explain this a little more.

Comment: In the context of this article he means that web applications/frameworks and the database engine are implementation details of a solution and not core pieces of the architecture. You should be able to change either of these details without having to redesign the system's architecture.

Comment: @dbugger's hit the nail on the head. This (https://vimeo.com/43612849) is worth watching as he elaborates on the ideas in that article.

Comment: @dbugger I understand the point. This detail word was confusing me.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Thanks for sharing this video lecture. It is very helpful

Comment: @mubeen it's also worth reading these:  http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture & http://natpryce.com/articles/000786.html. There are a number of variations on this architectural theme.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Good, Thanks for sharing. I also found this book http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420 It will also worth reading

Answer (score 1):

In object-oriented programming, we have found it works best to write any app in an abstract, domain-centric design; that is to say, it is best for the core of any app to be "a bunch of library classes" that know nothing about specific forms of input or output, such as the UI or database.  The article by Martin mostly discusses how to architect those classes.  Then, using those classes is the code that is specific to your UI and database.  The heart of your app knows nothing about whether it is a web app or a console app, or an app for touch-tone audio phones.

Thus the web, or the database, is a mere detail because it doesn't (and indeed cannot) affect the heart of your domain logic.

Of course, the web details can be complex and intricate, but ideally they would all be concerned with rendering the right HTML, Javascript, CSS, and content files and gathering input from the user, and "business logic" (or domain logic) would be left to the core system, and not web specific.

In today's web development landscape, rich client-side capabilities have made this scheme a little harder to grasp.  In the end, you may have two "domain systems": the main server-side domain code, which seems to be what Martin is discussing, and a client-side domain, which may have its own abstract domain-centric architecture, usually written in Javascript. Frameworks and libraries like Angular and Aurelia are trying to provide some extra tools to enable robust abstract domain-centric architectures on the client side.  For these client-side architectures, Uncle Bob might say the web services they call and the DOM they manipulate are "just details"; the heart of your domain-centric architecture is in the controller, library or service functions that your controllers and viewmodels interact with.

In addition to the resources mentioned in the comments, look up the concept of DDD (Domain-Driven Design) for more.